# what is the difference between a "var get return" statement over just a simple var

Tags: swift

As a beginner I am just wondering why it would be benefitial to user this statement

```
//first statement
 var email: String? {
        get {
            return emailField.text
        }
    }
```

over just this:

```
var email = emailField.text
```

I get it that the first code is instantiating the email variable outside a function , but I might as well just use the emailField.text throughout my code. Is this just a fance way of renaming the emailField.text to "email"? Or what is the deeper reason to create the first statement?

Comment: The first is a computed value - i.e. it will return whatever `emailField.text` is *at the time the call is made* to `.email`. The second one just assigns the value of `emailField.text` *at the time of assignment*. If the value never changes, it would be effectively the same as `let email = emailField.text` (`let` - read-only vs `var` - read-write)

Comment: I use that a lot, usually to remove the optional and some preprocessing, e.g. `return (emailField.text ?? "").trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)`. However, this can have multiple other uses cases too. For example, if `email` is to be used from another class, it's not a good practice for the other class to access internals (`emailField`) directly.

Comment: thank you for pointing out the difference between "at the time the call is made" and "the time of assignment" - totally makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code example is a computed value as noted in the comments and since there is only a getter, the value can never be set meaning you couldn't, for example, write `email = "new value"`.

The second example is a field and since it's a `var` you can read and write it. (I assume in your example it's a field and not just a local variable.)

Why is it beneficial? Depends on your use case. It's often desirable to make things immutable or to tightly control mutation. If this was a field on your class, you could write code in your class to modify the value of `emailField.text` but code outside of your class could be prevented from doing the same.

Perhaps you want to expose the value of what I assume is your text box to other parts of your program without also allowing them to mutate the value.

Comment: great explanation, yes, it totally makes sense now why the variable was set as a read only one. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One important reason to use these "computed properties" is to use them exactly for what the name suggests: compute stuff that depends on something else, whenever it's needed.

Consider for example:

```
struct Rectangle {
    var width: Double

    var height: Double

    var area: Double
}
```

Having an implementation like this forces you to make sure that whenever either `width` or `height` changes, you must remember to update `area` as well. Worse, what would happen if someone were to assign to `area`? You'd have no idea how to divide this value into `width` and `height`.

Computed properties come to the rescue:

```
struct Rectangle {
    var width: Double

    var height: Double

    var area: Double {
        return width * height
    }
}
```

not only is it now impossible to forget updating `area`, it's also no longer assignable.

Comment: excellent, so the computed var is actually read only and computed. Great explanation thanks